# When is Julia's convert() used?

Tags: julia

At http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/, there is a discussion about adding integers to floats and so on, and and at the end it says

> User-defined types can easily participate in this promotion system by defining methods for conversion to and from other types, and providing a handful of promotion rules defining what types they should promote to when mixed with other types.

From this I inferred that when defining my own numeric type, I simply needed to define how to convert it to a known type for it to work with functions on it. But I tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
julia> type MyType
           n::Int
       end

julia> convert(::Type{Int}, x::MyType) = x.n
convert (generic function with 1 method)

julia> convert(Int, MyType(1))
1

julia> MyType(1) + 1
ERROR: `+` has no method matching +(::MyType, ::Int64)
```

Answer (score 15):

There are two problems with your code:

- arithmetic operators such as `+` only promote subtypes of `Number`;
- you need to define a promotion rule in addition to the conversion function.

The following should do what you want:

```
module Test

import Base: convert, promote_rule

type MyType <: Number
    n :: Int
end

convert(::Type{Int}, x::MyType) = x.n

promote_rule(::Type{MyType}, ::Type{Int}) = Int

end
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between promotion and conversion?

Comment: `convert` tells the compiler how to perform the conversion from `MyType` to `Int` when it has been already decided to do so.  `promote_rule` tells the compiler which conversion to perform when it sees both `Int` and `MyType` as operands — whether to convert `MyType` to `Int` or `Int` to `MyType`.

Comment: With your code I am getting `ERROR: no promotion exists for MyType and Int64
 in + at promotion.jl:158`.

Comment: You likely need to restart the REPL, or use module qualification: `m = Test.MyType(5); m+3`. You may have a different notion of `MyType` already in your session.