# How to create Point type that can be used in matrix math

Tags: julia

I'd like to create a composite type `Point2D` with members `x` and `y`, which is easy enough.  But I'd like it to participate in the normal math functions with non-`Point2D`s.  For example, `Point2D(1,2) + [1,1]` should result in a `Vector{Int64}` of value `[2,3]`.

I created the `convert` and `promote_rule` functions based on [When is Julia's convert() used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594395/when-is-julias-convert-used), but then realized my type needs to be a subtype of something that is `convert`ed. However when I try to subtype from `Vector` or `Vector{T}` or any type of `Array` or `AbstractArray` in an attempt to make my type participate in the conversion, I get `ERROR: invalid subtyping in definition of Point2D`.  If as an experiment I make my type a subtype of `Number`, as in `type Point2D{T} <: Number`, then at least the file loads up without error, but of course when I try `Point2D(1,2) + [1,1]` I get `ERROR: no promotion exists for GridCalc.Point2D{Int64} and Int64`.

I also tried making my `Point2D` a `mutable struct` instead, but it also wouldn't "take" the `<: Vector{T}`.

Here is the code:

```
type Point2D{T}  # Fails when I add <: Vector{T}, etc.
    x::T
    y::T
end

# Convert a Point2D to a vector of the same type
convert{T1, T2<:Vector{T1}}(::Type{T2}, p::Point2D{T1}) = [p.x, p.y]

# Choose Vector when given the option
promote_rule{T1<:Real, T2<:Point2D{T1}, T3<:Vector{T1}}(::Type{T2}, ::Type{T3}) = T3
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right approach to let a `Point2D` participate in math functions as though it were a 2-vector?
2. How do I get my `Point2D` to be a subtype of `Vector{T}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to subtype `AbstractVector{T}`.  In Julia you can only subtype abstract types; `Vector{T}` is a concrete type.  You'll also have to implement a few required methods.  See the [interfaces chapter](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1) for more details:

```
julia> type Point2D{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
           x::T
           y::T
       end
       Base.getindex(p::Point2D, i::Int) = getfield(p, i)
       Base.size(::Point2D) = (2,)

julia> Point2D(1,2)
2-element Point2D{Int64}:
 1
 2

julia> [1 2; 3 4; 5 6] * Point2D(1,2)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 11
 17
```

You can also take a look at (and/or use) the [JuliaGeometry organization](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry) and [GeometryTypes.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/GeometryTypes.jl) for their point definition and surrounding methods.

Comment: Perfect!!  I knew I was close.  Thanks :)